# How to get names list of collection in firestore?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I have list of collection like this :
Surat Keterangan Penduduk, Surat Keterangan Pengantar, etc.

I want to get names list if collection not id of document, how to get it?

```
documentReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(currentUser.getUid()));

documentReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            String getName = documentReference.getId();
            Toast.makeText(AllMail.this, getName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to [list subcollections nested under a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document), there is no provided client API for that.  I suggest not using subcollections at all like this, and instead put each name in document under a known collection ID.  This known collection can be queried/listed by any client.