# How to print collection name under document in flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[![I want a booking system like as collection->appoinment_user_id->user_id(Who want to book)->date and time.[image: ][1]]][2]

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to get all subcollections under a document in the **client-side** SDKs for Firestore. The common pattern is to give collections *known* names, which you can type in your code, and only use generated IDs for documents.

So in your scenario you'd add a `users` collection under the `0Sj3n....` document, and then under *that* you'd add documents for the user IDs again.

Also see:

- [How to list subcollections in a Cloud Firestore document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596532/how-to-list-subcollections-in-a-cloud-firestore-document)
- [How to get names list of collection in firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62566164/how-to-get-names-list-of-collection-in-firestore)